# How to check execute update was done

Tags: angularjs

Editable in my angularjs it was running smooth when i editing 3 to 4 items in my table. After editing and press the save button it will automatic reload the page to change the value of other items that connected to the items that you edit.

The problem is when i change 52 items in my table it was not synchronize. after reload some items not change but when i reload by myself all data was edited and all good.

My hypothesis is when my loops run for 52 times for updates. i check my logs. I see that when execute the update. It will reload faster than my loops.

My conclusion is there possible to check the execution of the updates for 52 times in my logs??

Share your ideas it will be great if there are more options :)

**my controller:**

```
nums = []

$scope.saveTable = () =>
  for data in nums
    LeaveCredit.update(data)
  $route.reload()


$scope.checkRecord = (data, record) ->
  if data != record.no_of_days
    nums.push({ id: record.id, no_of_days: data })
```

Comment: is your update async or sync?

Comment: thanks for the reply it was sync

Comment: If `LeaveCredit.update` is actually async behind the scenes, it would explain the problem. Can you give us more detail about `LeaveCredit.update()`?

Comment: LeaveCredit.update() is resource to my routes and im giving a parameters of id and the value of my new items example LeaveCredit.update([id: 1, no_of_days:"15"]) after that it will update to my database and then i will reload my page

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the "update" api, and it's sync, you should have it return the updated version of your data so you can do this:

```
$scope.saveTable = () =>
  for data in nums
    data = LeaveCredit.update(data)
```

If you can do that, you won't need to `reload()` since the data will be updated live already.

If `update()` is asynch though, you might be able to use a promise interface for it like this:

```
$scope.saveTable = () =>
  for data in nums
    LeaveCredit.update(data)
      .then((updatedData) =>
        data = updatedData
```

(Not sure if that's good coffee)

Comment: you can give me js syntax i will do the conversion :)

Comment: the first source code was fine but i have another table that sync in leavecredits thats why i need to reload